# finding a row in excel vba issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with 3 columns. `Column 1, Column 2, Column 3`. I want to do a find criteria so I can get back the position of the Row. How is this possible?.

To find one criteria I can do ... but do not know how to extend so it finds the row that matches e.g. value 1, value 2 , value 3.

```
Columns("A").Find(value, Range(A:A), xlValues, xlWhole)
```

Comment: Would you like to return just the row number where the value is found or the values of the row itself?

Comment: Just the row number. I am doing further processing afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to hold the range, and then search the array to find the values. Once the values are found, it will output the row number which they have been found on.

```
Option Explicit
Sub matchCriteria()
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim valOne As String, valTwo As String, valThree As String

    valOne = "x" 'Update to reflect the values you want to find
    valTwo = "y"
    valThree = "z"
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrValues = Range("A1:C" & lrow)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
        If arrValues(i, 1) = valOne _
        And arrValues(i, 2) = valTwo _
        And arrValues(i, 3) = valThree Then
            MsgBox ("Row " & i & " contains the three specified values.")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The array currently will contain columns A:C. Let me know if you have any questions.